# How do I pass a callback function to sqlite3_exec in swift?

Tags: list, sqlite, swift

How do I pass a callback function to `sqlite3_exec` in Swift?

```
sqlite_str = sqlite_str + "\(sqlite_property_str))";

var str:NSString = sqlite_str;

var sqlite:COpaquePointer = share().sqlite3_db;
var errmsg:UnsafePointer<Int8> = nil

let rc = sqlite3_exec(sqlite, str.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding), <#callback: CFunctionPointer<((UnsafePointer<()>, Int32, UnsafePointer<UnsafePointer<Int8>>, UnsafePointer<UnsafePointer<Int8>>) -> Int32)>#>, <#UnsafePointer<()>#>, <#errmsg: UnsafePointer<UnsafePointer<Int8>>#>)
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 2.2 provides two options for implementing the `sqlite3_exec` `callback` function: (1) a global, non-instance `func` procedure or (2) a non-capturing literal `{}` closure.

The [sqlite.org](https://sqlite.org/)'s ["SQLite in 5 minutes or less"](https://sqlite.org/quickstart.html) example is implemented in a Swift Xcode7 project [here](https://github.com/marc-medley/004.65.sql-sqlite-in-5-minutes).

**Readable `typealias`**

```
typealias sqlite3 = COpaquePointer
typealias CCharHandle = UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>>
typealias CCharPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>
typealias CVoidPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>
```

**Callback Approach**

```
func callback(
    resultVoidPointer: CVoidPointer, // void *NotUsed 
    columnCount: CInt,               // int argc
    values: CCharHandle,             // char **argv     
    columns: CCharHandle             // char **azColName
    ) -> CInt {
    for  i in 0 ..< Int(columnCount) {
        guard let value = String.fromCString(values[i]) 
        else { continue }
        guard let column = String.fromCString(columns[i]) 
        else { continue }
        print("\(column) = \(value)")
    }
    return 0 // status ok
}

func sqlQueryCallbackBasic(argc: Int, argv: [String]) -> Int {
    var db: sqlite3 = nil 
    var zErrMsg:CCharPointer = nil
    var rc: Int32 = 0 // result code

    if argc != 3 {
        print(String(format: "ERROR: Usage: %s DATABASE SQL-STATEMENT", argv[0]))
        return 1
    }

    rc = sqlite3_open(argv[1], &db)
    if  rc != 0 {
        print("ERROR: sqlite3_open " + String.fromCString(sqlite3_errmsg(db))! ?? "" )
        sqlite3_close(db)
        return 1
    }

    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, argv[2], callback, nil, &zErrMsg)
    if rc != SQLITE_OK {
        print("ERROR: sqlite3_exec " + String.fromCString(zErrMsg)! ?? "")
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg)
    }

    sqlite3_close(db)
    return 0
}
```

**Closure Approach**

```
func sqlQueryClosureBasic(argc argc: Int, argv: [String]) -> Int {
    var db: sqlite3 = nil 
    var zErrMsg:CCharPointer = nil
    var rc: Int32 = 0

    if argc != 3 {
        print(String(format: "ERROR: Usage: %s DATABASE SQL-STATEMENT", argv[0]))
        return 1
    }

    rc = sqlite3_open(argv[1], &db)
    if  rc != 0 {
        print("ERROR: sqlite3_open " + String.fromCString(sqlite3_errmsg(db))! ?? "" )
        sqlite3_close(db)
        return 1
    }

    rc = sqlite3_exec(
        db,      // database 
        argv[2], // statement
        {        // callback: non-capturing closure
            resultVoidPointer, columnCount, values, columns in

            for i in 0 ..< Int(columnCount) {
                guard let value = String.fromCString(values[i]) 
                else { continue }
                guard let column = String.fromCString(columns[i]) 
                else { continue }
                print("\(column) = \(value)")
            }
            return 0
        }, 
        nil, 
        &zErrMsg
    )

    if rc != SQLITE_OK {
        let errorMsg = String.fromCString(zErrMsg)! ?? ""
        print("ERROR: sqlite3_exec \(errorMsg)")
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg)
    }
    sqlite3_close(db)
    return 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of that C function (the third argument of `sqlite3_exec`) is the thing you passed into the fourth argument of `sqlite3_exec`. Therefore, it's possible to pass a Swift closure into `sqlite3_exec`.

```swift
// Define a Type for later loading in the C function
typealias RowHandler = (
    Int32,
    UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>?>?,
    UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>?>?
) -> Void

// The Swift closure to pass into sqlite3_exec
var rowHandler: RowHandler = { count, names, values in
    // Do anything you want
}

let state = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &rowHandler) { rowHandlerPointer in
    
    return sqlite3_exec(
        connection,
        "SOME SQLITE STATEMENT",
        { rowHandlerRawPointer, columnCount, values, columns in
            
            // Load the pointer as the Type of the closure
            let rowHandler = rowHandlerRawPointer!.load(as: RowHandler.self)
            
            // Use it!
            rowHandler(columnCount, columns, values)
        },
        rowHandlerPointer, // This will become rowHandlerRawPointer in the C function
        nil
    )
}
```

Because `RowHandler` is a Swift closure type, we can make it a parameter of a wrapper method:

```swift
class SQLiteDatabase {
    
    // Define a closure type for later loading in the C function
    typealias RowHandler = (
        Int32,
        UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>?>?,
        UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>?>?
    ) -> Void
        
    var connection: OpaquePointer?

    // Other methods...
    
    func execute(_ statement: String, receiveRow: @escaping RowHandler) -> Int32 {
        
        
        // The Swift closure to pass into sqlite3_exec
        var rowHandler = receiveRow
        
        let state = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &rowHandler) { rowHandlerPointer in
            
            return sqlite3_exec(
                connection,
                statement,
                { rowHandlerRawPointer, columnCount, values, columns in
                    
                    // Load the pointer as the Type of the closure
                    let rowHandler = rowHandlerRawPointer!.load(as: RowHandler.self)
                    
                    // Use it!
                    rowHandler(columnCount, columns, values)
                },
                rowHandlerPointer, // This will become rowHandlerRawPointer in the C function
                nil
            )
        }
        
        return state
    }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
func result(database: SQLiteDatabase) -> [[String: String]] {
    
    
    var rows = [[String: String]]()
    _ = database.execute("SOME STATEMENT") { (count, names, values) in
        var row = [String: String]()
        for index in 0..<Int(count) {
            guard let name = names?[index], let value = values?[index] else { continue }
            row[String(cString: name)] = String(cString: value)
        }
        rows.append(row)
    }
    return rows
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is (currently) not possible. The Xcode 6 beta 4 release notes state:

> However, you cannot call a C function pointer or convert a closure to
>   C function pointer type.

As a workaround, you could put `sqlite3_exec` together with its callback into a
C wrapper function and call that from Swift.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to provide an update to @l --marc l answer for Swift 3 and Linux which helped me get up and running. Thank you @l --marc l !

**Callback Approach**

```
func callback(
    resultVoidPointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>?, // void *NotUsed 
    columnCount: Int32, // int argc
    values:UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>?, // char **argv     
    columns:UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?>? // char **azColName
    ) -> CInt {
    var dic: [String:String] = [:]
    for  i in 0 ..< Int(columnCount) {
        guard let value = values?[i] 
        else { continue }
        guard let column = columns?[i] 
        else { continue }

        let strCol = String(cString:column) 
        let strVal = String(cString:value)

        dic[strCol] = strVal
        //print("\(strCol) = \(strVal)")
    }
    resultSet.append(dic)
    return 0 // status ok
}

func sqlQueryCallbackBasic(dbStr:String, query:String) -> Int {
    var db: OpaquePointer? 
    var zErrMsg:UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?
    var rc: Int32 = 0 // result code

    rc = sqlite3_open(dbStr, &db)
    if  rc != 0 {
        print("ERROR: sqlite3_open " + String(sqlite3_errmsg(db)) ?? "" )
        sqlite3_close(db)
        return 1
    }

    rc = sqlite3_exec(db, query, callback, nil, &zErrMsg)
    if rc != SQLITE_OK {
        let errorMsg = zErrMsg
        print("ERROR: sqlite3_exec \(errorMsg)")
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg)
    }

    sqlite3_close(db)
    return 0
}
```

**Closure Approach**

```
func sqlQueryClosureBasic(dbStr:String, query:String) -> Int {
    var db: OpaquePointer? 
    var zErrMsg:UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>?
    var rc: Int32 = 0

    rc = sqlite3_open(dbStr, &db)
    if  rc != 0 {
        print("ERROR: sqlite3_open " + String(sqlite3_errmsg(db)) ?? "" )
        sqlite3_close(db)
        return 1
    }

    rc = sqlite3_exec(
        db,      // database 
        query, // statement
        {        // callback: non-capturing closure
            resultVoidPointer, columnCount, values, columns in
            var dic: [String:String] = [:]
            for i in 0 ..< Int(columnCount) {
                guard let value = values?[i]
                else { continue }
                guard let column = columns?[i]
                else { continue }

                let strCol = String(cString:column)
                let strVal = String(cString:value)

                dic[strCol] = strVal

                //print("\(strCol) = \(strVal)")
            }
            resultSet.append(dic)
            return 0
        }, 
        nil, 
        &zErrMsg
    )

    if rc != SQLITE_OK {
        let errorMsg = zErrMsg
        print("ERROR: sqlite3_exec \(errorMsg)")
        sqlite3_free(zErrMsg)
    }
    sqlite3_close(db)
    return 0
}
```

**Test**

```
import Glibc

var resultSet: [[String: String]] = [[:]]

//sqlQueryClosureBasic(dbStr:"Sqlite_Test.db", query:"SELECT * FROM Employee")

sqlQueryCallbackBasic(dbStr:"Sqlite_Test.db", query:"SELECT * FROM Employee")


for row in resultSet {
    for (col, val) in row {
        print("\(col): \(val)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update for the given answers to support Swift 5.5.1

```
    let db: OpaquePointer = // the database connection
    let sql: String = // the sql string

    func callback(context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?,
                  columnCount: Int32,
                  values: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>?>?,
                  columns: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>?>?) -> Int32 {
        guard let values = values else { return 0 }
        guard let columns = columns else { return 0 }

        for column in 0 ..< Int(columnCount) {
            guard let columnNamePtr = columns[column] else { continue }
            guard let valuePtr = values[column] else { continue }

            // Note: String(cString:) will copy the values from C to Swift
            let column = String(cString: columnNamePtr)
            let value = String(cString: valuePtr)
            print("\(column) = \(value)")
        }

        return 0 // status ok
    }

    var errorMessage = UnsafeMutablePointer<CChar>(nil)
    sqlite3_exec(db, sql, callback, nil, &errorMessage)

    if let errorMessage = errorMessage {
        print(String(cString: errorMessage))
    }
```